# Codename one version 1.0 is installed even though I install version 6.0 from Eclipse Marketplace

Tags: codenameone

I am using Eclipse 2020-06 (I have made a fresh install of Eclipse instead of upgrading it from an earlier version of Eclipse) and JDK 8 (1.8.0_261). My OS is Windows 10.

JAVA_HOME is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_261

When I download "Codename One" plugin from Eclipse Marketplace it shows the version as 6.0 and it says "Installed" at the end of the installation process.

However, when I go to "Help -> Eclipse IDE -> Installation Details" under Eclipse, CodenameOneFeature version is listed as: 1.0.0.201409151325

When I select CodenameOneFeature from this list and hit Update, it says "No updates found". So basically I cannot force it to update to 6.0.

I can confirm that I have the earlier version installed also from the setting of the Codename One projects I create: when I go to Properties -> Java Compiler, the compliance level is set to 1.5 (also 1.5 is used in build.xml file).

BTW, I have also tried installing Eclipse 2019-06 (instead of 2020-06) and/or installing JDK 10 (instead of JDK 8) and/or modifying the eclipse.ini (by adding -vm option) so that it uses the version of JDK I want (instead of setting JAVA_HOME). But no combination of those has solved the problem.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the CodenameOneFeature via the Eclipse IDE Installation Details dialog, and try installing again?

Comment: Yes I have tried installing Codename One several times last night and I have also changed my Eclipse and JDK version and re-tried but this did not fix the issue. I have tried it again just now: I have uninstalled CodenameOneFeature from Eclipse IDE Installation Details, then reinstall it from Eclipse Marketplace, again it installed version 1.0. I should also mention that other people I know that tries to install CN1 using Eclipse and Windows 10 is currently having the same problem. So I do not think this problem is specific to me.

Comment: I should also say that this problem is specific to fresh installs of Eclipse. I had another system that had Eclipse Photon onto which I have installed Codename One and over the years I have updated its Eclipse version and Codename One version. Now it has Eclipse 2020-06 and Codename One 6.0 (it does not list CodenameOne 1.0 in installation details). I use JDK 8 on this system as well. So if you want to reproduce this problem at your end please do a fresh install of Eclipse 2020-06, instead of upgrading Eclipse from an earlier version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated answer:**

I found the problem. I broke the update site with a commit a couple of weeks ago. This should be fixed in a couple of hours once server caches refresh.

**Original answer:**

With Eclipse at this time we only support JDK 8. We're experiencing issues in updating the eclipse plugin to the latest version. Once installed I think you can also use JDK 11 but it doesn't matter since we don't support JDK 11 features.

Once a reasonably new version of the plugin is installed you can press update in Codename One Settings and it will update our libraries to the latest version equivalent to the other IDEs.

Comment: I have JDK 8 and only version that I can get from Eclipse Workspace for CodenameOneFeature is 1.0.0.201409151325 (as mentioned above). When I create Codename One projects and right click on the project, I see "Codename One" menu, but I do not have the option to press "update". So I think I do not have  "reasonably new version of the plugin installed". It gives me an option to "refresh libs" . When I select this option, it does not update things properly since when I build the code it still complains from things like "error: package com.codename1.charts.util does not exist".

Comment: How can I force Eclipse to install a reasonably new version of the plugin ? When do you think you will be able to fix the issues in updating the Eclipse plugin to the latest version?

Comment: Eclipse itself needs to be installed on top of JDK 8. It's not enough to have it in the system it needs to be defined as the VM powering eclipse in ini. Furthermore, you should use ZuluFX as the VM due to the CEF migration that's in progress. I think we'll release a new version right after the 7.0 release which would mean probably December/January time frame.

Comment: I am positive that Eclipse is using JDK 8 to run itself since JAVA_HOME is set to it and I have also specified JDK 8 as a VM option in eclipse.ini. But still the only version that can be downloaded from Eclipse Marketplace is 1.0.0.201409151325. Because when it downloads the plugin, I believe it connects to https://codenameone.com/files/eclipse/site.xml and the version on this site is this one. Is it possible for CodenameOne to specify a newer version on this site so that we can install "reasonably new version of the plugin". This way we maybe able to "press update in Codename One Settings".

Comment: I edited the answer. Turns out this was just a stupid site regression. I'm still trying to figure out how this happened

Comment: Thanks @shai-almog. When the server catches refresh and the problem is solved, should I uninstall and reinstall Eclipse plugin? Do you think this simple step would allow me to download the latest version of Codename One? Or do I need to do something extra?

Comment: The server is up to date. There's no need to uninstall, update should work fine

Comment: Yes now I can download version 6.0. Thanks!